# Scala convert Seq to k, v of sbt.Project.Setting[_]

Tags: scala, build, playframework, sbt, seq

Play 2.0's Build.sbt uses a pimped Project definition to do its magic; any additional settings you might need to add must be manually entered in `k := v` fashion. Works fine for the general case, but not for the specific; namely, when needing to set an sbt-plugin's settings which invariably are `Seq[Settings[_]]`. Here's an example of what predictably works

```
lazy val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, ....).settings(
  version := appVersion
)
```

Now, how to get Seq[Settings[_]] converted to k,v pairs so the Play by-name call:

```
def apply(...., ...., settings: => Seq[Setting[_]])
```

actually works?!!

I've asked over on play-user, but good luck, a zoo over there, framework is taking off and core devs are clearly up to their ears...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work?

```
….settings(mySeqOfSettings: _*)
```

Comment: @Debiliski thanks, tried that earlier, compiler complained with, "such annotations are only allowed in arguments to *-parameters". Serious, brow furrowing pain here, driving me nuts ;-)

Comment: @Debs actually you are right in the singular case; I have several Seq[Settings[_]] to pass in, however; that's where I'm getting hosed. Perhaps some flatMap or reduce magic is in order

Comment: `(seq1 ++ seq2): _*` – or do you want to eliminate duplicate keys?

Comment: this works as well: "seqSettings.flatMap{x=>x}: _*", where I made seqSettings a Seq of Seqs. I like your ++ however, you get the nod ;-)

Comment: Instead of `flatMap{x=>x}` `flatten` would also be possible.

Comment: ++ seems more sbt-esque, although flatten indeed looks better than flatMap in this case.  Thanks for the assist!

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem with play framework and sbt-buildinfo plugin. After a lot of trial and error, I ended up preferring applying the settings twice in a row.  I felt like it looked more obvious what was happening in Build.scala: http://mfizz.com/blog/2013/04/auto-generate-class-file-build-info-play-framework